# How to measure the Kumo cloud thickness?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, finance

How to measure the ichimoku cloud thickness?

Hi. The ichimoku kinko hyo is an indicator used in financial analysis. The kumo cloud can be used to describe volatility, based on it's thickness.
How do you measure a kumo cloud's thickness to describe it as "thick" or "thin"? The solution I am thinking of is to build a sample data set from 
the difference between span A and span B, and then find the coefficient of variance for that sample set. Then if this figure is less than 2, 
I could say the cloud is "thin" but if its higher than 2, I would say the cloud is "thick". Is this a reasonable approach?.

Comment: Would [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) be a better fit for tthis question?